# Changing all Button background except button clicked

Tags: c#, winforms, buttonclick

I am working on a form that has lots of buttons. When the user clicks one button the background should change color. If they click another button on the form its background should change color and the previous buttons color should return back to the original color.

I can do this by hard coding in every button but this form has alot of buttons. I am sure there has to be a more efficient way of doing this

I have this so far

```
foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
{
    if (c is Button)
    {
        if (c.Text.Equals("Button 2"))
         {
             Btn2.BackColor = Color.GreenYellow;
         }
         else
         {

         }
    }
}
```

I can get the background for Btn2 to change. How would i change the background for all the other buttons in the form. Any ideas how i could do this without having to hardcode each button.

Comment: Did you try c.BackColor in your else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code below will work without regard to the number of buttons on the form.  Simply set the `button_Click` method to be the event handler of all buttons.  When you click on a button, its background will change color.  When you click on any other button, that button's background will change color, and the previously-colored button's background will revert to the default background color.

```
// Stores the previously-colored button, if any
private Button lastButton = null;
```

...

```
// The event handler for all button's who should have color-changing functionality
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Change the background color of the button that was clicked
    Button current = (Button)sender;
    current.BackColor = Color.GreenYellow;

    // Revert the background color of the previously-colored button, if any
    if (lastButton != null)
        lastButton.BackColor = SystemColors.Control;

    // Update the previously-colored button
    lastButton = current;
}
```

Comment: I had to place `current.BackColor = Color.GreenYellow;` under `lastButton = current;` otherwise if I clicked on a button twice it would remove the color.

Answer (score 0):

This will work as long as you don't have any control containers (eg Panels)

```
foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
{
   Button btn = c as Button;
   if (btn != null) // if c is another type, btn will be null
   {
       if (btn.Text.Equals("Button 2"))
       {
           btn.BackColor = Color.GreenYellow;
       }
       else
       { 
           btn.BackColor = Color.PreviousColor;
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if your buttons are inside of a panel do the code below, in foreach
you will get all the buttons inside of pnl2Buttons panel and then try to pass the text name of the button that you want to change the background
and the rest will have a SeaGreen color.

```
foreach (Button oButton in pnl2Buttons.Controls.OfType<Button>())
{
   if (oButton.Text == clickedButton)
   {
       oButton.BackColor = Color.DodgerBlue;
   }
   else
   {
       oButton.BackColor = Color.SeaGreen;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on the answer from @Brett Wolfington in 2013...

You can use a simple method to reduce the code in the mouse `button_Click` events methods.

Below I use the method `Chgcolor` and invoke it via a one liner in my `button_Click` events. It helps to reduce the redundancy and by calling `current.BackColor = Color.GreenYellow;` after all the checks I can now click on 1 button repeatedly without the color disappearing.

Example below from Visual Studio community 2022

```
    private Button? lastButton = null;

    private void Chgcolor(Button current) 
    {
        if (lastButton != null)
        {
            lastButton.BackColor = SystemColors.Control;
        }

        lastButton = current;
        current.BackColor = Color.GreenYellow;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Chgcolor((Button)sender);//call the check color method
    }

    private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Chgcolor((Button)sender);//call the check color method
    }
```

[image]